# Material form fields give datepicker the same height as other fields

Tags: css, sass, angular-material

i have a form with 3 fields:

[image]

While selection and text have same height and are fitting well the datepicker is not.
What is the most easy and stable (in regards of other style changes and screensizes) to have all 3 always appearing well aligned (same height, same upper and lower border, same font-size)

i only found [this issue](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/11663) and changing font-size only in datepicker is not an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a quick solution you can overwrite the padding in the class mat-form-field-flex.
example:

```
.mat-form-field-flex {
  padding-top: 3px;
}
```

You have to do it in the global stylesheet and if you would not do it for all date pickers use a identifier (id, class,...) for the form field to use as a reference.

Cheers